# installing a new jar maven eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, m2e

I am trying to install a jar called icepdf-core.jar in maven/eclipse.

I am running the following command after which the org.icepdf.core folder is created in ~.m2/repository but the jar file is not being installed in the directory.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/Users/me/Downloads/ICEpdf-4.1.4-bin/icepdf/icepdf-core.jar 
                         -DgroupId=org.icepdf 
                         -DartifactId=core 
                         -Dversion=4.1.4 
                         -Dpackaging=jar 
                         -DgeneratePom=true
```

After running this command, I manually copied the core-4.1.4.pom.xml and maven-metadata-local.xml into the local_repo folder in my eclipse project.

I also added the dependency in pom.xml as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.icepdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>icepdf-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I am getting errors in eclipse saying:

> Missing artifact org.icepdf:icepdf-core:jar:4.1.4:compile

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 4):

You can also import the jar into your maven repo using m2e if you're on eclipse indigo. Go to *file/import/maven/install or deploy an artifact to a maven repository*

You will need just to fill up the group and artifact id

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891107

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are doing something wrong: in your Maven `install-file` command, you indicate that the `artifactId` is **core**, but in your dependency definition, you are using the `artifactId` **icepdf-core**.

Try to re-install your artifact with the following Maven command:

> mvn install:install-file
>   -Dfile=/Users/me/Downloads/ICEpdf-4.1.4-bin/icepdf/icepdf-core.jar
>   -DgroupId=org.icepdf -DartifactId=icepdf-core -Dversion=4.1.4 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true

Comment: Hi, I tried again and looks like it worked. I still have a question though, I don't see the jar file being copied in .m2/repository, but my Java classes are picking up these classes from this jar file. How exactly is this working?